# Adjusting box width to ensure anchor elements wrap to next line - for Codrops' Inline Anchor Styles kit

Tags: html, css

I’m leveraging [Codrops](http://www.codrops.com)’ slowly aging but still relevant ‘Inline Anchor Styles’ kit. Codrops’ [original live demo can be found here](http://tympanus.net/Development/InlineAnchorStyles/). For my site, I’m using the ‘link-arrow’ theme.

I’ve got most of it to work as intended. My problem is that I can’t figure out how to make the longer anchor tagged web links to wrap to the next line.

[Here is my reduced test case](https://codepen.io/Angeles4four/pen/ZEWpvda?editors=1100) on CodePen, which also shows the HTML and CSS I am working with. When you are viewing that Pen, if you reduce the size of your  browser window, you’ll notice that the very first web link is obscured and extends way over to the right beyond the boundary of the window. What I am trying to do is make the web links wrap to the next line (similar to the way the regular non-anchor tag `<li>` contents already do).

To further clarify what I am trying to accomplish, you can take a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73xpL.jpg) on imgur. There are 4 red arrows pointing to the anchor tag contents which extend beyond the browser window.

How do you get the content inside the anchor tags to wrap to the next line?

After importing Codrops' HTML, CSS, and JS source code linked to above, these are the only modifications I've made:

```
body {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 133%;
    margin: auto;
}
.box {
    margin-left:-60px;
}

li {
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

ol {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ol.dashed {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  ol.dashed > li {
    text-indent: 5px;
  }
  ol.dashed > li:before {
    content: "-  ";
    text-indent: 5px;
  }

.container {
  width:100%;
}
```

**What I’ve tried**:

I’ve tried adjusting `width` and `max-width` values from 100% progressively down to 50% for all the elements in play including the `body`, `ol`, `li`, `a` elements in addition to the classes in play such as  `.container` and `.box`. No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have carefully checked your code on codepen and Codrops's Inline Anchor Styles.

I have found a very simple solution after analyzing your problem, there are two places where the code needs to be adjusted is:

[image]

this code code must not include line `white-space: nowrap`, it should be removed. When removing we need to setup after position of anchor from `top: 0`

[image]

And boom now we changed two snippset as follows:

[image]

```css
section a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    color: #404d5b;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.link-arrow a::after {
    left: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 1em;
    background: #34495e url('./arrow_right.svg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: 60% auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    pointer-events: auto;
    top: 0
}
```

Now Your Anchor tag will not be overflown again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Umar_Ahmed's code snippet, I was able to reduce the solution down to this:

```
section a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: normal;
}

.link-arrow a::after {
  pointer-events: auto;
  top:0;
 }
```

But I am giving full credit to Umar as the official answer to my question. ;)

Thank you Umar!